# How can I find out the mean value of each group of numbers in y, that have the same index in x?

Tags: math, matlab

I want to write such a code for two matrixes:

```
x=[1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3]';
y=[11 21 31 24 32 33 13 37 3]';
```

How can I find out the mean value of each group of numbers in y, that have the same index in x?

My algorithm can look like:

```
If     x(1)=x(2) counter1=1 sum1=y(1)+y(2) 
       x(2)=x(3) counter1=2 sum1=sum+y(3)  Define  newx1=x(1) newy1=sum1/counter1
       x(3)<>x(4) 
       x(4)=x(5) counter2=1 sum2=y(4)+y(3)  Define  newx2=x(4) newy2=sum2/counter2
       x(5)<>x(6) 
       x(6)=x(7) counter3=1 sum3=y(6)+y(7)  
       x(7)=x(8) counter3=2 sum3=sum+y(8)  
       x(8)=x(9) counter3=3 sum3=sum+y(9)  Define  newx1=x(6) newy3=sum3/counter3
```

My problem here is using more then two counters in a loop. Probably, I should write something like:

```
s=1:8
for k=1:9
if x(k)=x(k+s);
else
s=s+1;
end
end
```

which didn't work:(
I'll be greatfull for any help or advise!

Comment: This makes no sense to me. Can you please clarify what you are trying to do? Also, you do know that Matlab has a highly optimized `mean` function, right?

Comment: @PengOne thank you for your answer. Yes, I know mean function of matlab but I have to create my own function, which I may change  somehow. So, what I want to do is create another matrix xnew=[1 2 3]from x getting only one of the equal ones and a ynew=[(11+21+31)/3 (24+32)/2 (33+13+37+3)/4] Could I explain better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want the mean of each group of numbers that have the same index in "x". In that case...

```
function FindAverages
x=[1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3]';
y=[11 21 31 24 32 33 13 37 3]';

means = [];
indexes = unique(x);
for i=1:numel(indexes)
    index = indexes(i);
    indexInY = (x==index);
    means(end+1) = mean(y(indexInY));
end
disp(means);
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use [GRPSTATS](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/grpstats.html) function available in Statistical Toolbox. It can apply a function by groups:

```
x=[1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3]';
y=[11 21 31 24 32 33 13 37 3]';
grpstats(y,x,@mean)
```

Alternative option (if you don't have Statistical Toolbox, for example)) is to use [GROUP2CELL](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/11192-group2cell) submission on FileExchange. It put numbers corresponding to a particular category into a separate cell in a cell array. Then you can apply many functions, including mean with CELLFUN:

```
cellfun(@mean,group2cell(y,x))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly your question you could simply use accumarray, it should works faster then a loop.

```
%#Input
x=[1 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3]';
y=[11 21 31 24 32 33 13 37 3]';

[newx, idx]=unique(x,'legacy');
newy=accumarray(x(:),y(:),[],@mean);  %#groups every element of 'y' according to the index of 'x' and applies the function '@fun' to each group.
%#Output
newy =[21.0000 28.0000 21.5000];
newx=[1 2 3];     %#returns the index used for each group
idx=[3 5 9];      %#returns the index of the last observation for each group
```